# Linkedin Like bot

Tags: node.js

I have a bot that logs in as different users and likes the latest post by a company. 3 weeks ago it stopped working. I didn't notice because on my end when I ran it, everything seemed fine. But if you go to the Linkedin pages the articles have not been liked. It was working perfectly up until that point.

I'm convinced it has something to do with Linkedin changing something up.

Here is the main code :

```
const config = require('./config')
const logger = require('./logger')
const { all } = require('./options')
const { sanitize } = require('./util')

module.exports = async (page, company) => {
    logger.info(`Go to ${company} page...`)

    await page.goto(`${config.get('url')}/company/${company}/`)

    logger.info('Waiting for new articles...')

    const feed = await page.waitForSelector('#organization-feed')
    await feed.hover()

    let article

    while (
        article = await page.waitForSelector('#organization-feed .feed-shared-update-v2').catch(() => null)
    ) {        
        await article.hover()

        const button = await article.$('.feed-shared-social-action-bar [aria-label="Like"]')
        
        if(button === null)
        {
            await page.evaluate(node => node.remove(), article);
            await page.waitFor(config.get('sleep'))
            await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy({ top: -100 }))
            await page.waitFor(100)
            await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy({ top: 1000 }))
            continue;
        }

        await button.hover()
    
        const liked = await page.evaluate(node => node.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'true', button)
        const text = await page.evaluate(node => node.querySelector('.feed-shared-text').innerText, article)

        if (!liked) {
            logger.info(`Like → ${sanitize(text)}...`)
            await button.click({ delay: 20 })
        } else if (!all) {
            break
        }

        await page.evaluate(node => node.remove(), article)
        await page.waitFor(config.get('sleep'))
        await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy({ top: -115 }))
        await page.waitFor(100)
        await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy({ top: 1000 }))
    }
}
```

When I view what's happening, the bot opens the browser, logs in as the user, goes to the company page and starts scrolling the articles. It used to click the like button at this point, but it seems like it's missing the like button now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin changed their aria labels from [aria-label="Like"] to [aria-label="Like company-names' post"] Just had to update my code to that